# What circuit components should I use for a vacuum?

Tags: electrical, relay

So I'm constructing a dust extractor system for my workshop, and I need to figure out a circuit. I have 3D Printed a connector that connects two PVC Pipes, and has a hole for a wooden slab. I can insert the wooden slab (which has a large hole in it) to control whether or not the the pipe is open or closed. I'm thinking of creating a circuit that uses a limit switch  and a relay to control the power to the vacuum. I live in Australia and my volts and amps from an outlet is 230V and I believe 10 amps. Which limit switches and relays should I use to control my vacuum. And is there any suggestions to improve this circuit.

Comment: this question is far too broad and poorly specified. I am not even sure what you are trying to describe.

Comment: what do the pipes, the pipe connector and the wooden slab have to do with an electrical question?

Comment: I think you're trying to turn the vacuum on automatically when the pipe is open?  Hard to tell - this question needs more detail and clarity.